# CasperJs : unable to perform click on div tag

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to click a div tag which is having an class name.

```
<div role="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="tableCell menu settings" data-type="settings">
    <div class="carTitle" data-dojo-attach-point="_carTitle">xyz car </div>  
</div>
```

Clicking on any div tag(i.e, class="tableCell menu settings" or class="carTitle"), redirects to next page but no operation was performed when tried this way.

```
var carSelector = 'div.carTitle';

...
casper.then(function() {
if (!this.exists(carSelector)) return;
    this.click(carSelector);
});
```

Please help me, if i am going wrong somewhere?

Found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270861/casperjs-how-do-i-click-a-remote-div-and-then-update-its-class-name) but not of much help.

PS : In general, explain how to work with div tags(click operation) in casperjs ?

Comment: If the `div.carTitle` really has an `onclick` listener then this should work. Are you sure that there isn't another `div.carTitle` higher up in the DOM without such a handler?